# Start WebActivator from unit test

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, mstest, webactivator

I am trying to write integration tests. Therefore I need the start methods of WebActivator to be executed in the pre-start initialization stage of my unit tests.

I tried this

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTests
{
    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void Init(TestContext c)
    {   
        WebActivator.ActivationManager.Run();
    }
```

But it would always give me error message:

```
Unable to create instance of class EL.NET.SecurityAdapter.Tests.UnitTests. Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: This method can only be called during the application's pre-start initialization stage..
```

with a stacktrace like this

```
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ThrowIfPreAppStartNotRunning()
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.LegacyModuleRegistrar.RegisterModule(Type moduleType)
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(Type moduleType)
<myproject>.Tests.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon.Start() in <myprojectPath>Tests\App_Start\NinjectWebCommon.cs: line 25
System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
WebActivator.BaseActivationMethodAttribute.InvokeMethod()
WebActivator.ActivationManager.RunActivationMethods[T]()
WebActivator.ActivationManager.Run()
<myproject>.Tests.UnitTests..ctor() in <myprojectPath>Tests\UnitTests.cs: line 40
```

I know that unit tests should work with mocks, but I really need those integration testing.

Comment: Your application must be hosted on a web server if you ever expect to be able to run this method. Integration tests are usually done by deploying your application on some server and then trigerring HTTP requests to it and verifying the response. There are frameworks that could help you automate those web tests. Ultimate versions of Visual Studio have this functionality built-in.

Comment: Well I thought they added "Support for invoking the start methods outside of ASP.NET"... But i cannot get it working (http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/02/new-features-in-webactivator-13.html?showComment=1340099397689#c7847093432479571136)

Comment: Hi, could you post the whole stack trace? You need to only call `WebActivator.ActivationManager.Run();`, it will call pre start methods.

Comment: I tried to use the Run() method only, same error occurred. I added the complete stacktrace to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to run the WebActivator to create my Ninject mappings.

I ended up creating a wrapper interface for the DI container. My repositories access the DI only via this wrapper.

In the web application I use a Ninject-specific implementation of this interface, and for the tests I have made a custom implementation.

I still think that it should be possible to make Ninject work in unit tests somehow, but for now this also works.